# Where in the world is this harbour town?

Tags: italy, where-on-earth, identify-this, mediterranean

Does anyone know where the place depicted on this TV is? I'm hoping it's not a digital confabulation because it looks very nice and I'd like to visit:

[image: Image taken from:https://img.kasa.cz/k-foto/800/0/5/9/product_2116950.jpg]

Image depicted is a product image of an LG 42LF652V. No attribution is given by LG on their website for this image.

Comment: Looks like Amalfi Coast: https://www.mondoguide.it/city-tours-from-amalfi-coast

Comment: @Karlson There are some photographs of this town online that are identified as Amalfi coast, but the only one I've found that identifies the town isthe one on the Wikipedia article for Cinque Terre, which identifies it as Vernazza. The photo in the question is mirrored -- flipped on the vertical axis.

Comment: @phoog is right. The photo is mirrored.

Comment: OP: Please provide proper attribution of your image

Comment: the "cinque terre" (literally "five lands") is perhaps the most famous strip of the mediterranean coastline .. it's sort of the muzak of "images of mediterranean towns!"  Considering that was an advertising image for LG highlighting their image quality, it's astounding what a bad job the art director did on the mock up image!  it's all squished, color is ruined, not to mention reversed!!  heh!

Comment: And does the sea around Amalfi really slope that much? Looks like a great place for water-skiiing!

Comment: really!  what a joke for a professional advertising image!

Comment: Just in case someone looks for 'colorful places' or somesuch I would like to add although not an answer to the original question: Reykjavík in Iceland is surprisingly colorful! http://www.politico.eu/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/8235193581_64828c00b1_o.jpg And now going on a subjective limb: perhaps even more vibrant colors than Vernazza.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It looks like it's Vernazza, one of the [Cinque Terre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinque_Terre) - five very cute and colourful towns on the Italian coast. The photo seems to be shot as much the same as this image, but flipped for some reason:

[image: Vernazza]
<sup>Image by chensiyuan [ [GFDL](http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/fdl.html) or [CC BY-SA 4.0-3.0-2.5-2.0-1.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0-3.0-2.5-2.0-1.0) ], via Wikimedia Commons</sup>

Unfortunately, your visit might be more difficult than you'd like. Some media reports say that local government [are limiting tourist visitors with a ticketing system](http://www.theguardian.com/world/2016/feb/17/italy-to-impose-limits-on-visitors-to-cinque-terre-with-tourist-ticket-system) - so you'd best work on getting your hands on those tickets. However, other websites seem to dispute the existence of these tickets, for example, [inqinqueterre.com](https://www.incinqueterre.com/en/cinque-terre-card) says:

> Attention! There are no restrictions on visiting Cinque Terre in 2016! Do not trust unverified sources of information that spread the news of the visitors’ limitation - this information is not correct!.

It is possible that in reality the number of tickets for walking certain footpaths in the area will be restricted  but Wikivoyage among others indicate that there are numerous non-ticketed footpaths.

As I can't find any official sources on limiting visitors, I am somewhat doubtful of the reality of this ticketing system.

It's also worth noting that the colours won't look quite as vibrant in reality - the saturation and colours in that image are definitely tuned up.

Comment: Thanks for your additional information. I'll accept Tom's answer as he was first to answer, with what looks like to me the correct village. Many thanks.

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon Note my edited update - seems the Guardian may be talking rubbish.

Comment: Thanks. Given the update and extra information I've now accepted this answer as it's the 'best' rather than just first. I appreciate the extra info.

Comment: Maybe we should ask [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) why the image was flipped.

Comment: Or someone's making money selling people unnecessary tickets.

Comment: In 2013, neither the area nor the paths required tickets.  One path had a booth for an admission price, but no one said anything when we walked right past it.  Unfortunately, at that time, most of the main path was closed due to hazards.

Comment: If I googled that correctly, it seems that the corresponding google maps location is here: https://www.google.co.nz/maps/search/Cinque+Terre+/@44.1353904,9.6818492,18.54z

Comment: If I may submit a hypothetical reason why the image might be reversed: I tried to use Google Image Search to find the source of this image. The only results I got were pages featuring LG televisions - even when I cropped out the bezel of the television. It's possible the manufacturer uses this as a technique to ensure that content indexing on search engines only finds their product as a search result.

Answer (score 14):

Vernazza, Italy on the Riviera

Comment: yes, but do you know where to get the best gelato??

Comment: Gelateria Stalìn. By far the best in Vernazza. Has nothing to do with the dead dictator.

Comment: @JoeBlow - No I don't because I am not a gelato (or any other type of ice cream) fan.